# Prevent user from including file extension in file name in air application

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, file-format, xml

So I have an air application that I want to save data from into an custom file. Below is my code. My question is, this code is checking if the user has not typed the ".bar" in their file name, and if they haven't, the program will add it onto the end of the file name.

My question is, if a user types "newFile.foo", it saves the file as "newFile.foo.bar". How can I prevent either the user from typing an extension, or maybe have the application remove the ".foo" part, or any other option that will achieve the desired results.

Thanks.

```
var file:File = File.desktopDirectory
file.browseForSave("Save");// Create a <projectStrings /> node
var projectStrings:XML = new XML(<projectStrings />);
// Create a <strings /> node
var strings:XML = new XML(<strings />);
strings.@stringOne = "Hello";
strings.@stringTwo = "World";
// Add the <strings> node to the <projectStrings> node.
projectStrings.appendChild(strings);

var saveFile:File = File(e.target);
var directory:String = saveFile.url;
if (directory.indexOf(".ugags") == -1) {
    trace("WRONG");
    directory += ".ugags";
}
var file:File = new File(directory);
var fileStream:FileStream = new FileStream();
fileStream.open(file, FileMode.WRITE);
fileStream.writeUTFBytes(projectStrings);
fileStream.close();
```

Comment: Since this is a programming question that is not gamedev-specific and would not get a better answer from a game developer than a general programmer, [it is off topic](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/faq#questions) and belongs on SO.

Comment: You shouldn't, if the user desire a dot in the file name let him have it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use lastIndexOf String's method to detect file's extension like that:

```
var nameStart:int = Math.max(fileName.lastIndexOf("/"), fileName.lastIndexOf("\"));
var extStart:int = fileName.lastIndexOf(".");
if (ext <= nameStart)
{
  //no extention at all
  fileName += ".foo";
}
else
{
  if (fileName.substr(extStart) != ".foo")
  {
    //user given other extension
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A fancy regular expression would do this more concisely. But you can just split on the "." and then reassemble the parts w/your requirements.

```
var fileParts:Array = directory.split('.');
var lastIndex:int = fileParts.length - 1;
var lastPart:String = fileParts[lastIndex];
// reassmble the initial parts
directory = "";
for (var i:int = 0; i < lastIndex; i++)
{
    if (i != 0)
        directory = directory + "_" + fileParts[i];
    else
        directory = fileParts[0];
}

if (lastPart == "ugags")
    directory += ".ugags";
else
    directory = directory + "_" + lastPart + ".ugags";
```